# Tomcat 6 - authentication through active directory with encrypted password

Tags: authentication, tomcat, encryption, active-directory, digest

I am trying to connect to tomcat with an active directory user. 
When the password is in plain text like the following:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"   
connectionURL="ldap://localhost:389"     
connectionName="user_name" 
connectionPassword="password"       
userBase="OU=blabla,DC=aaa,DC=com"       
userSubtree="true"      
userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"   
userRoleName="memberOf" 
roleBase="OU=blabla,DC=aaa,DC=com"   
roleName="cn"    
roleSubtree="true"         
roleSearch="(member={0})"        />
```

the authentication is ok. BUT, I don't want a password in my configuration file.

I tried the following:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"   
connectionURL="ldap://localhost:389"    
digest="MD5" 
connectionName="user_name"  
connectionPassword="encrypted_password"        
userBase="OU=blabla,DC=aaa,DC=com"       
userSubtree="true"      
userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"  
userRoleName="memberOf"
roleBase="OU=blabla,DC=aaa,DC=com"   
roleName="cn"   
roleSubtree="true"       
roleSearch="(member={0})"        />
```

but the authentication fails.
I didn't find any solution. 
I will really appreciate any help

thank you

Comment: Do your users a favor and do not use Basic auth. Use SPNEGO with AD: http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I think your only alternative is to subclass JNDIRealm and make a new attribute that will have some sort of encrypted connection password. The password can't be hashed (with, e.g. MD5 as you specify) because hashes are one-way--there's no undoing a hash--and Tomcat needs the password in its original unhashed form to authenticate against the AD installation.

If you use a reversible encryption in your JNDIRealm subclass, then when Tomcat needs the password you can decrypt the password and pass it along.

Comment: I did as you suggested. I created a subclass to JNDIrealm which overrides the getConnectionPassword. It gets the encryoted password and decrypts it. I can connect now. But now, somthing changed, and when I try to do login with a user, the authentication fails. I checked the source code, I don't see the connection between getConnectionPassword and getUserPassword. I will really appriciate your help. I can't login with a user

Comment: Without seeing the specific setup I don't know how much more help I can be... I don't know the specific AD configuration, for example... but I will say that at times like this, I like to pull out Wireshark and look at the communications (or attempts) between Tomcat and the AD server, see what's actually going on. Try that, maybe? Also, try adding `adCompat="true"` to the Realm config... it acts slightly differently for Active Directory vs. other LDAP.